# Automapper profile when using anonymous types

Tags: automapper

I've used Automapper in the past for mapping simple DTO, but now I've to do a little bit sophisticated thing and I want to know if it's possible.

Please consider the following snippet of code

```
       var query = from tipo in _artistaTipoRepository.GetAll()
                            join storico in _artistaTipoStoricoRepository.GetAll()
                                on tipo.Id equals storico.Id
                            where storico.Versione == 0
                            select new 
                            {
                                tipo,
                                storico 

                            };
                
                var entities = await query.ToListAsync();

                foreach (var entity in entities)
                {
                   var dizionarioItem = Mapper.Map<ArtistaTipoDizionarioViewModel>(entity);

                   result.Add(dizionarioItem);
                }
                return await Task.FromResult(result);
```

Now what I want to do is have a Profile that takes this anon type and fills the properties of the ArtistaTipoDizionarioViewModel (I've still not created the ArtistaTipoDizionarioViewModelProfile.cs since I don't know what to put inside) .. is it possible via a profile? How should I pass it? I know that if I create an object that has 2 properties Tipo and Storico it would work but is there a way I can do it without having to create it?
Thanks

Comment: Tip: Use ValueTuples instead of Anonymous Types (though you still need to use Anonymous Types with EF, but convert them to ValueTuples immediately after you get the query results).

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: @dai no luck... I'm on 4.6 :/

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I've not such an entity related... that why in my linq select I used an anonymous type

Comment: @advapi Why are you targeting .NET 4.6? **Every platform that supports 4.6 can be updated to 4.8**. There is no reason to not use .NET Framework 4.8 today. In the unlikely event there are any breaking changes then there are "feature flags" you can set in your `app.config` to work around them.

Comment: You're making your life difficult :) Just add the FKs and `ProjectTo` will certainly help.

Comment: I can't... It's a quite big solution... and I can't update Framework or add foreign keys!

Comment: @dai I've referenced the System.Tuple, but do you've a working sample? it keeps saying me it can't map Tuple<X,Y> to my VM type

Comment: @advapi `Ssytem.Tuple` is not the same thing as `ValueTuple`. If you're stuck on .NET 4.6 then it's not worth using value-tuples.